# Can't get image to load on mouseover event

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling

I have 2 div containers that are side by side. The left div has an unordered list with 3 li elements. Each li has a unique ID. I'm trying to get an onmouseover event on the 1st li to load a PNG file into the right div.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="twoCol">
   <ul class="storeList">
   <li id="level_1">Richmond</li> <!-- mouseover loads png in 2nd div --> 
   <li id="level_2">Santa Maria</li>
   <li id="level_3`enter code here`">Venezula</li>
  </ul>
  </div> 

 <div class="twoCol" id="jsContent">

  <!-- load png into this div via mouseover on ID: level_1  -->

 </div>
```

Here's my javaScript:

```
var storeHours = newObject();
storeHours.img = document.createElement("img");
storeHours.src = "store_hours.png";
storeHours.img.appendChild(storeHours.src);

var liElement1 = document.getElementById("level_1"); // ID for 1st li element

var addContent = document.getElementById("jsContent"); // ID for div to load png

liElement1.onmouseover = function() {
addContent.appendChild(storeHours.img);     
};
```

Comment: `var storeHours = newObject();` typo?

Comment: The better way to do object calling would be using literals. `var storehours = {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo in your JavaScript: separate `new` and `Object` in `var storeHours = newObject();`.

Second, in `appendChild()` you must provide a node element, and what you are creating with `storeHours.src = "store_hours.png";` is actually a string.

You have two options:

1. Use the traditional `setAttribute()` method:

```js
var storeHours = new Object();
storeHours.img = document.createElement("img");
//storeHours.src = "store_hours.png";
//storeHours.img.appendChild(storeHours.src);
storeHours.img.setAttribute('src', 'store_hours.png');
```

2. If you want to follow the object approximation, use the `setAttributeNode()` method:

```js
var storeHours = new Object();
storeHours.img = document.createElement("img");
//storeHours.src = "store_hours.png";
//storeHours.img.appendChild(storeHours.src);
storeHours.src = document.createAttribute('src');
storeHours.src.value = 'store_hours.png';
storeHours.img.setAttributeNode(storeHours.src);
```

Answer (score 0):

src is an attribute of img element but not a child.
Try

```
storeHours.img.src = storeHours.src;
```